# Fastest way to copy files in Java

Tags: java, file-io

What ist the fastest way to copy a big number of files in Java. So far I have used file streams and nio. Overall streams seem to be faster than nio. What experiences did you make so far?

Comment: Are you doing some kind of transformation on the files as you copy them? Why not just use the OS's filesystem functions?

Comment: No I'm not doing any transformations. But the error handling would be much harder when copying 10,000+ files and the overhead of spawning a system thread when copying small files is to big.

Comment: I recommend you amend your question to include the constraints we've discovered.

Comment: How many do you want to do in parallel?

Comment: Did you try tar pipeline? rsync?(Sys admins could help here - could be for ServerFault)

Comment: Usually NIO is faster, and using one thread per drive is optimial.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

http://www.baptiste-wicht.com/2010/08/file-copy-in-java-benchmark/ might get you your answer.

> For the benchmark, I made the tests using different files.
>
> 1. Little file (5 KB)
> 2. Medium file (50 KB)
> 3. Big file (5 MB)
> 4. Fat file (50 MB)
> 5. And an enormous file (1.3 GB) only binary
>
> And I made the tests first using text files and then using binary files. I made the tests using in three modes :
>
> 1. On the same hard disk. It's an IDE Hard Disk of 250 GB with 8 MB of cache. It's formatted in Ext4.
> 2. Between two disk. I used the first disk and an other SATA Hard Disk of 250 GB with 16 MB of cache. It's formatted in Ext4.
> 3. Between two disk. I used the first disk and an other SATA Hard Disk of 1 TB with 32 MB of cache. It's formatted using NTFS.
>
> I used a benchmark framework, [described here](http://www.baptiste-wicht.com/2010/04/write-corrects-benchmarks/), to make the tests of all the methods. The tests have been made on my personal computer (Ubuntu 10.04 64 bits, Intel Core 2 Duo 3.16 GHz, 6 Go DDR2, SATA Hard Disks). The Java version used is a Java 7 64 bits Virtual Machine...

Answer (score 10):

I would use:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.channels.*;

public class FileUtils{
    public static void copyFile(File in, File out) 
        throws IOException 
    {
        FileChannel inChannel = new
            FileInputStream(in).getChannel();
        FileChannel outChannel = new
            FileOutputStream(out).getChannel();
        try {
            inChannel.transferTo(0, inChannel.size(),
                    outChannel);
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            throw e;
        }
        finally {
            if (inChannel != null) inChannel.close();
            if (outChannel != null) outChannel.close();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
        FileUtils.copyFile(new File(args[0]),new File(args[1]));
  }
}
```

If any of your files are bigger than 64M in Windows you might need to look at this:
http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=439695&messageID=2917510

Comment: catch (IOException e) {
            throw e;
        }   <--- nice one

Comment: Thanks this was massively quicker than what I was using!

Comment: My IDE is warning me that I should close the InputStream rather than the channel... Any comment on this?

Comment: @basZero https://stackoverflow.com/a/8210815/313137 says they should both work

Comment: @unbeli catch (IOException e) { throw new RuntimeException(e) } could be better

Comment: This is sample code. Not production code. Written 10 years ago.

Answer (score 2):

**Using Stream**

```
private static void copyFileUsingStream(File source, File dest) throws IOException {
    InputStream is = null;
    OutputStream os = null;
    try {
        is = new FileInputStream(source);
        os = new FileOutputStream(dest);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            os.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
    } finally {
        is.close();
        os.close();
    }
}
```

**Using Channel**

```
private static void copyFileUsingChannel(File source, File dest) throws IOException {
    FileChannel sourceChannel = null;
    FileChannel destChannel = null;
    try {
        sourceChannel = new FileInputStream(source).getChannel();
        destChannel = new FileOutputStream(dest).getChannel();
        destChannel.transferFrom(sourceChannel, 0, sourceChannel.size());
       }finally{
           sourceChannel.close();
           destChannel.close();
       }
}
```

**Using Apache Commons IO**

```
private static void copyFileUsingApacheCommonsIO(File source, File dest) throws IOException {
    FileUtils.copyFile(source, dest);
}
```

**Using Java SE 7 Files**

```
private static void copyFileUsingJava7Files(File source, File dest) throws IOException {
    Files.copy(source.toPath(), dest.toPath());
}
```

**Performance test**

```
File source = new File("/Users/tmp/source.avi");
File dest = new File("/Users/tmp/dest.avi");

//copy file conventional way using Stream
long start = System.nanoTime();
copyFileUsingStream(source, dest);
System.out.println("Time taken by Stream Copy = "+(System.nanoTime()-start));

//copy files using java.nio FileChannel
source = new File("/Users/tmp/sourceChannel.avi");
dest = new File("/Users/tmp/destChannel.avi");
start = System.nanoTime();
copyFileUsingChannel(source, dest);
System.out.println("Time taken by Channel Copy = "+(System.nanoTime()-start));

//copy files using apache commons io
source = new File("/Users/tmp/sourceApache.avi");
dest = new File("/Users/tmp/destApache.avi");
start = System.nanoTime();
copyFileUsingApacheCommonsIO(source, dest);
System.out.println("Time taken by Apache Commons IO Copy = "+(System.nanoTime()-start));

//using Java 7 Files class
source = new File("/Users/tmp/sourceJava7.avi");
dest = new File("/Users/tmp/destJava7.avi");
start = System.nanoTime();
copyFileUsingJava7Files(source, dest);
System.out.println("Time taken by Java7 Files Copy = "+(System.nanoTime()-start));
```

**RESULTS**

```
Time taken by Stream Copy            =  44,582,575,000
Time taken by Java7 Files Copy       =  89,061,578,000
Time taken by Channel Copy           = 104,138,195,000
Time taken by Apache Commons IO Copy = 108,396,714,000
```

Comment: Better to just paste this link https://www.journaldev.com/861/java-copy-file :)

Comment: @Mak Pasting links is not good because links can end up dead in the future. For example: An oracle link in one of the non-accepted answers no longer works.

Answer (score 1):

Have java fork off an OS batch script that copies the files.  Your code might have to write the batch script.

Comment: Already thought about that but the error handling would be to hard when copying 10,000+ files and the overhead of spawning a system thread when copying small files is to big. Furthermore the app wouldn't be platform independent.

Comment: 1. You're going to have to handle error checking anyway.  2. You're correct in that it would not be platform independent - so you intend to run this on servers of different types?  3. Can you create the 10,000 files in the 'proper' place to begin with and not need a copy at all?  4. Don't spawn one thread per file.  One thread per 100 files or something.

Comment: I agree with this. Dumb copying of files is not an ideal use case of Java. If you want to do it from Java, then fork off an OS level call.

Answer (score 1):

You can use  either FileUtils implementation of apache commons-io library to copy file

```
FileUtils.copyFile(new File(sourcePath), new File(destPath));
```

Which uses *FileChannel* for IO operation.

Or use 
`java.nio.file.Files`'s `copy()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Its depend of files(bigger files), for me is fastest way this one with buffered stream

```
 public void copyFile(File inFileStr, File outFileStr) throws IOException {

    try (BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(inFileStr)); 
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outFileStr))) {

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 1024];
        int read = 0;
        while ((read = bis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            bos.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }

        bis.close();
        bos.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```